# IFilter not working on Microsoft Server 2012 R2 x64

Tags: windows, dll, powerpoint, windows-server-2012-r2, ifilter

I execute a program on Windows 10 x64 and works fine, but I execute the same program on Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 and get "Could not find a 32 bits IFilter dll for a file with an '.pptx' extension"

The program is a C# program that use IFilter to parse some files and get the text

I download all the Update for Microsoft Filter and still not working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The app was working in Platform target: "Any CPU" and Prefer 32-bit so the app search for the 32 bits dll.

Just uncheck the Prefer 32-bit and change the Platform target to "x64" for the project